# Counting digits in given String

Tags: java, string, digit, charat

I need to sum all digits in a given string. So for I've got this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input string");
    String ciag = odczyt.nextLine();

    int suma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ciag.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ciag.charAt(i))) {
            suma += ciag.charAt(i);
        }
    } 
    System.out.println(suma);
}
```

When I input:

> "Ala got 3 apples and 1 orange"

the output is 100 instead of 4. What should I change to make it count only digits?

Comment: If that was “Ala got 13 apples and 1 orange”, would you require 14 or 5? In other words, should it still process the digits individually?

Comment: Yes, every digit should be added on it's own.

Answer (score 5):

The problem occurs here:

```
suma += ciag.charAt(i);
```

you're adding the character code rather than the digit itself.

change it to this:

```
suma += Integer.parseInt(ciag.charAt(i)+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are adding the ascii code of numbers. Just subtract '0' from the char number as shown below:

suma += ciag.charAt(i)-'0';

Comment: The idea is right. Still better to use `Character.getNumericValue(ciag.charAt(i))`.